# How to check if int32_t number can fit in int8_t and int16_t?

Tags: c++, c, clang

I have a int32_t number and i need to check if will it fit in int8 and in16 but when i try:

```
    if (number ==(int32_t)((int8_t) number)) {
    printf("%s %d\n","8", number);
    
} else if (number ==(int32_t)((int16_t) number)){
    printf("%s %d\n","16", number);
```

Compiler says that first if statement is always true, but i don't know how to do it in other way, using only "==" and bits operations like << >>. and <stdint.h>.

Comment: You can check if m-bit value fits into n-bits if its upper m - n bits are zero.

Comment: `int8_t` as the name suggest takes 8 bits, so if your input `number` is 32 bits, you can check if oldest 24 bits are non zero. You can use bit mask to do that.

Comment: Is this a challenge to do it without `<=`, `>=` and the limits constants?

Comment: @e2-e4 it's c language

Comment: `if(number >= INT8_MIN && number <= INT8_MAX)`

Comment: I notice the restriction "using only `==` and bits operations like `<<` `>>`" but with signed variables you are on dodgy ground.

Comment: @MichaelPalichTerentev The code in the question is exactly how I'd do it. Can you show the exact warning text, and tell what compiler you use?

Comment: @MichaelPalichTerentev your code looks OK and it works fine for me.

Comment: yep. works : https://godbolt.org/z/5WjevYsMM

Answer (score 10):

As of C++ 20 you can do this:

```
std::in_range<std::int8_t>(-1)
```

see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_range)

Comment: Does that compile in C?

Comment: Well, no worries. It seems your answer is interesting enough in C++ even if the Q is in C.

Comment: @e2-e4 This is exactly why we 1) don't answer questions before the OP has clarified the language, and 2) don't remove a language tag when there are answers posted in that language. See [C and C++ tag usage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) in the respective wiki, it contains advise for how to moderate posts that are cross tagged. Particularly: _"Be careful about re-tagging questions once there are answers posted, particularly if there are already both C and C++ answers posted. In such cases, the tags should be left alone, since changing them would make posted answers invalid."_

Comment: @Lundin Noted, thanks. Please put the C++ tag back if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> How to check if int32_t number can fit in int8_t and int16_t?

Like this:

```
extern std::int32_t value;

if (value <= std::numeric_limits<std::int8_t>::max()
 && value >= std::numeric_limits<std::int8_t>::min())
```

I expect `std::int16_t` case to be trivial based on this.

---

Since C++20, there is a [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65127048/2079303).

Comment: i can't use <= => , limits , and INTn_MAX constants

Comment: @MichaelPalichTerentev Why not?

Comment: @MichaelPalichTerentev We don't want to do your homework ;)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in some of the comments, your original approach of just casting the values should work.

```
if (number == (int32_t)((int8_t) number)) {
  printf("%s %d\n","8", number);   
} else if (number == (int32_t)((int16_t) number)){
  printf("%s %d\n","16", number);
}
```

However, if you are required to do bit manipulations yourself (which is a bit unclear from your comments), then here are some other possible options.

Unsigned values:

You could just mask off the upper bits, by using the 'and' operation `&` with the maximum value for the smaller type.

If these numbers are both equal, it means the value would fit in the smaller type. If not, it means some of the upper bits were used (and got masked off) so the values would be unequal.

For instance, an 8-bit number maximum would be `11111111` or `255`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

if (number == (number & UINT8_MAX)) {  // Mask off the upper 24 bits
  printf("%s %d\n","8", number);
} else if (number == (number & UINT16_MAX)) {  // Mask off the upper 16 bits
  printf("%s %d\n","16", number);
}
```

Signed values:

For signed values, it's a bit trickier given your restrictions. Additionally, C/C++ do not appear to define a strict way of representing negative numbers, so it may vary by compiler. However, I believe my solution below should work for both one's complement and two's complement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Handle negative numbers by converting them to positive value.
// We will still need to handle the minimum (i.e. most negative) value, in
// case of two's complement.
int isNegative = ((originalNumber >> 31) != 0);
int positiveNumber = isNegative ? number * -1 : number;
    
if ((isNegative && (number == INT8_MIN)) ||
    (positiveNumber == (positiveNumber & INT8_MAX))) {
  printf("%s %d\n","8", number);
} else if ((isNegative && (number== INT16_MIN)) ||
           (positiveNumber == (positiveNumber & INT16_MAX))) {
  printf("%s %d\n","16", number);
}
```

Comment: I misread the original post. Will update to handle signed integers. Good catch. Also the OP mentioned they need to use bitwise operations and not logical comparisons (e.g. `<=`). It's also tagged with both `c` and `c++`, so I hard coded the limits rather than relying on `std` namespace.

Comment: for negative `number` you can try `if (std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min() == (number & std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::min()))`

Comment: I believe the author is writing in C (but it's a bit unclear). I updated the code to use `<stdint.h>` rather than hardcoding values.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is positive, you can mask out the bottom 8 or 16 bits and compare.
If the number is negative, you have:

- For numbers between -1 and -128 (fits in eight bits), the 25 top bits are all set.
- From -129 and down, there is at least one zero in the top 25 bits.
- For numbers between -1 and -32768 (fits in 16 bits), the 17 top bits are all set.
- From -32769 and down, there is at least one zero in the top 17 bits.

So, something like this, perhaps:

```
char* answer[] = { "no", "yes" };
if (!(number >> 31))
{
    printf("Fits in eight: %s\n", answer[number == (number & 0xff)]);
    printf("Fits in 16: %s\n", answer[number == (number & 0xffff)]);
}
else
{
    printf("Fits in eight: %s\n", answer[(number >> 7) == 0x1ffffff]);
    printf("Fits in 16: %s\n", answer[(number >> 15) == 0x1ffff]);
}
```